# Is there a financial benefit for PhD student to join a funded research project

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom

I'm a first year PhD in Computer Science at a UK university. Recently, my supervisor has asked me to join a funded research project consisting of other post-docs and lecturers, i.e. I'll be the only PhD student in that project. My supervisor believes that it will be helpful for me to join since my research topic and a project's theme have many similarities, which I also agree. However, he doesn't mention anything about if I get paid to work in that project. So, I wonder if it is normal for a PhD student to work in a funded research project without getting paid.

Comment: In my field, funding and what projects people are effectively working on are sometimes pretty disjoint things. Do you currently get funding out of *any* project? If that is the case, I do not see a problem with you joining the new project. However, if you are not getting any money (or only a small stipend) I would certainly recommend negotiating.

Comment: Also, I should add that joining a project with many more senior people that is in a relevant topic to your PhD will likely be in fact beneficial to you.

Comment: @xLeitix: I receive partial funding from the university but not from any project. I also agree with you on that benefit, that's the reason I don't want to push or offend anyone from the project by asking about financial benefit :)

Comment: In computer science it is very common (one might say usual) to be paid as a PhD student (although as xLeitix said, funding is not necessarily related to the project you are working on). I suggest you talk to your supervisor about this.

Comment: @user12635 Well, asking for funding shouldn't offend anybody.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not in the U.K., but in my part of the world, it's common (one might say usual) for computer science PhD students to be paid. Is the determination of whether a PhD student is paid related to whether the project is funded? Not necessarily.

### When is it appropriate to ask about payment?

Should you talk to your supervisor about this? Instead of asking

> Is it normal to *not be paid*?

ask yourself

> Is it unusual to be paid?

In any scenario in which is is *not unusual* to be paid, it is neither inappropriate nor offensive to (politely) ask whether you can be paid for work you are doing.* In your case, it is definitely appropriate. So, go ahead and talk to your supervisor about this.

<sub>* [Here](http://scholarlyoa.com/2013/12/24/journal-editor-agrees-to-review-paper-then-demands-payment/) is an example of a scenario where it is not usual to be paid, and it was therefore inappropriate to ask for payment. As you can see, it's an extreme example :)</sub>